# Options for tuning mongoose

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and having a hard time understanding the different flag used inside connect() method which are passed inside the second object argument.

```
const connectDB = async() => {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{
        useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex:true, useFindAndModify:false, useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation available for [`mongoose.connect`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect).

> [options] «Object» passed down to the MongoDB driver's connect()
>   function, except for 4 mongoose-specific options explained below.
>
> - [options.bufferCommands=true] «Boolean» Mongoose specific option. Set to false to disable buffering on all models associated with this
>     connection.
> - [options.dbName] «String» The name of the database we want to use. If not provided, use database name from connection string.
> - [options.user] «String» username for authentication, equivalent to options.auth.user. Maintained for backwards compatibility.
> - [options.pass] «String» password for authentication, equivalent to options.auth.password. Maintained for backwards compatibility.
> - [options.autoIndex=true] «Boolean» Mongoose-specific option. Set to false to disable automatic index creation for all models associated
>     with this connection.
> - [options.useNewUrlParser=false] «Boolean» False by default. Set to true to opt in to the MongoDB driver's new URL parser logic.
> - [options.useUnifiedTopology=false] «Boolean» False by default. Set to true to opt in to the MongoDB driver's replica set and sharded
>     cluster monitoring engine.
> - [options.useCreateIndex=true] «Boolean» Mongoose-specific option. If true, this connection will use createIndex() instead of
>     ensureIndex() for automatic index builds via Model.init().
> - [options.useFindAndModify=true] «Boolean» True by default. Set to false to make findOneAndUpdate() and findOneAndRemove() use native
>     findOneAndUpdate() rather than findAndModify().
> - [options.reconnectTries=30] «Number» If you're connected to a single server or mongos proxy (as opposed to a replica set), the
>     MongoDB driver will try to reconnect every reconnectInterval
>     milliseconds for reconnectTries times, and give up afterward. When the
>     driver gives up, the mongoose connection emits a reconnectFailed
>     event. This option does nothing for replica set connections.
> - [options.reconnectInterval=1000] «Number» See reconnectTries option above.
> - [options.promiseLibrary] «Class» Sets the underlying driver's promise library.
> - [options.poolSize=5] «Number» The maximum number of sockets the MongoDB driver will keep open for this connection. By default,
>     poolSize is 5. Keep in mind that, as of MongoDB 3.4, MongoDB only
>     allows one operation per socket at a time, so you may want to increase
>     this if you find you have a few slow queries that are blocking faster
>     queries from proceeding. See Slow Trains in MongoDB and Node.js.
> - [options.bufferMaxEntries] «Number» The MongoDB driver also has its own buffering mechanism that kicks in when the driver is
>     disconnected. Set this option to 0 and set bufferCommands to false on
>     your schemas if you want your database operations to fail immediately
>     when the driver is not connected, as opposed to waiting for
>     reconnection.
> - [options.connectTimeoutMS=30000] «Number» How long the MongoDB driver will wait before killing a socket due to inactivity during
>     initial connection. Defaults to 30000. This option is passed
>     transparently to Node.js' socket#setTimeout() function.
> - [options.socketTimeoutMS=30000] «Number» How long the MongoDB driver will wait before killing a socket due to inactivity after
>     initial connection. A socket may be inactive because of either no
>     activity or a long-running operation. This is set to 30000 by default,
>     you should set this to 2-3x your longest running operation if you
>     expect some of your database operations to run longer than 20 seconds.
>     This option is passed to Node.js socket#setTimeout() function after
>     the MongoDB driver successfully completes.
> - [options.family=0] «Number» Passed transparently to Node.js' dns.lookup() function. May be either 0, 4, or 6. '4' means use IPv4
>     only, '6' means use IPv6 only, '0' means try both.

Comment: *"Both should probably be false if you are using the latest driver."* - Umm. No. Read that statement through again. One should clearly be `true` using the latest driver. Also the `useUnifiedTopology` *may* indeed be aimed at "replica set" connections, however there really is no sane reason for ever connecting to a MongoDB that is not configured as a replica set. Even a single node can be configured this way, and since that enables all the necessary "bells and whistles" of larger configurations (transactions, changestreams), you would simply not be of sound mind to do it any other way.